# Clone roaming Appdata in two places

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, folder-redirection

I have my users appdata (roaming) stored on a external server in the location that they're normally in.  I have some users that are in two locations equally.  This provides a problem when someone tries to open up Firefox on a computer in a location other than where their appdata is stored, it takes forever.

Is there a way that I can clone the redirected appdata (roaming) folder to two locations and have the folder redirection look for appdata (roaming) based on the location that the user is at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking that DFS is the answer.

Comment: Glad to help...